# JDBC program to select data from one table and insert into another table in different db

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

i am new to java, i am trying to insert a data from old_db to new_db.
i have tried a program to do that, its shows a error like "syntax error" cant find what the error.

the program has to getconnection to 2 postgres db and select data in a table and insert them into
another database table. both table have same fields and datatype.

```
import java.sql.* ;   
public class con2 
{ 
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{ 
try 
{ 
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/old_db","postgres","password");
try
{
   Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new_db","postgres","password");

 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 Statement st1 = con1.createStatement();   
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users"); 



  int val = st1.executeUpdate("insert into users("+"'rs()'"+")");

        rs.close();
                        st.close(); 
                    st1.close(); 



}
catch(SQLException e) 
  { 
         System.out.println( "could not get JDBC connection for new_db: " + e ); 
  } 
}
catch(SQLException e) 
  { 
         System.out.println( "could not get JDBC connection for  old_db: " + e ); 
  } 
} 
}
```

i am using jdbc4

Comment: Your program fails to escape data and is critically vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://bobby-tables.com/ . -1 because you **always show the exact text of the error message** if you're asking people to help you with it.

Comment: Perhaps not so vulnerable, since no data is passed in.  But it'll be a valid point for a real program.

Comment: @duffymo Sure, data is passed in - from the other database. Where a correctly written but not very paranoid program might well have inserted `');--drop schema public;--` in a field this one uses due to failed attacks on it. XSS-style attacks are entirely possible with SQL injection.

Comment: Agreed; your point is well taken, Craig Ringer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a program like shown below, it's working.

Thanks for the suggestions.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/old","user","pass");
            Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/new","user","pass");

            String sql = "INSERT INTO users("+ "name,"+ "active,"+ "login,"+ "password)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

            Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            PreparedStatement pstmt = con1.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String nm = rs.getString(2);
                Boolean ac = rs.getBoolean(3);
                String log = rs.getString(4);
                String pass = rs.getString(5);

                pstmt.setString(1, nm);
                pstmt.setBoolean(2, ac);
                pstmt.setString(3, log);
                pstmt.setString(4, pass);

                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("could not get JDBC connection: " +e);
        } finally {
            con.close();
            con1.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite wrong:

```
  int val = st1.executeUpdate("insert into users("+"'rs()'"+")");
```

You have to iterate over the `ResultSet` and `INSERT` each row.

I'd recommend a `PreparedStatement` to bind variables and a batch `INSERT`.

There are lots of other things I'd recommend that you change, but start with that and make the code work.

Two try/catch blocks nested this way is a bad idea.  One will do.

Close your resources in a finally block.

This is only an example, but why do you have to SELECT and bring the data to the middle tier at all?

And why reinsert the data that's already there?

The question, as posed, makes *no sense whatsoever*.  Voting to close.

Comment: Hi duffymo, is it possible to move data across databases in JDBC without bring data into middle tier?

Comment: if you're going to move data between databases, I'd recommend using an ETL tool and leaving Java out of it.  "in JDBC" means "middle tier" to me, so my answer is "no, it's not possible."

Answer (score 1):

One another way to do this is using [DBLinks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/dblink.html) in PostgreSQL.

Comment: if we use dbLink, queries performed in one table will also get performed in other table too right ?